# Log In with Apple ID

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication

I am developing an Application where I want the user to log in with his/her Apple ID.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is an standard API for this. You *could* use a `UIWebView` to make a user log in to an existing login form somewhere on apple.com, and then check for the subsequent success or failure URL, but that would probably be both brittle and rejected by the App Store approval process.

Answer (score 3):

Apple introduced [Sign In with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/) at their worldwide developer conference, WWDC 2019.

Here's how Apple describe it:

> Sign In with Apple makes it easy for users to sign in to your apps and websites using their Apple ID. Instead of filling out forms, verifying email addresses, and choosing new passwords, they can use Sign In with Apple to set up an account and start using your app right away. All accounts are protected with two-factor authentication for superior security, and Apple will not track users’ activity in your app or website.

Sign In with Apple requires iOS 13 or later, iPadOS 13 or later, watchOS 6 or later, macOS Catalina 10.15 or later, and tvOS 13 or later.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible currently.  Your best bet is to submit a feature request at https://bugreport.apple.com/

If you want to authenticate users without setting up your own registration system, you could adopt Facebook Connect.  Lots of people already use Facebook obviously, and you don't have to maintain the signup/forgot password/security stuff at all.

If you don't like Facebook, Google also offers a similar system. (see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps)

Answer (score 1):

Apple will probably never allow you to log in with the user's Apple ID.

You might be able to allow your users to log into Game Center. The user's Game Center account is tied to the AppleID, so users can be identified by your app that way. But this is assuming that you were actually building a game.

Apple's Game Center documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/15_GameCenter/GameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH7-SW1

The [App Store Review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) preclude using any information from Apple's services in your app, which is why it's dubious they would ever allow you to login with an Apple ID:

```
12. Scraping and aggregation

12.1
Applications that scrape any information from Apple sites (for example from apple.com, iTunes Store, App Store, iTunes Connect, Apple Developer Programs, etc) or create rankings using content from Apple sites and services will be rejected
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is a seamless user experience between the user's different iOS devices without requiring the user to pick a username and password for your service you could maybe use iCloud. But of course it depends on what you are building. Apple provides some videos introducing the different iCloud APIs: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/